# ANGULAR - ng-deep SCSS not working overnight

Tags: angular, ng-deep

I have my application right here : https://github.com/edissyum/opencapture/

Yesterday all was okay, but today I notice all my `::ng-deep` SCSS directive stopped working…

For example, the branch `dev_v2` is okay but `dev_nch` is not. For example, the notifications services have a black background instead of a white one...

I tried to revert package.json to old ones, but still the same error. I try to compile with another computer using different npm & node version, still the same error

Do you have any idea of the issue ?

EDIT : Yesterday I made a build-prod on the `dev_v2` branch and it's working good. Today, if I pull the branch, `build-watch` or `build-prod` will break `ng-deep`...

Thanks

Comment: Hi, ::ng-deep is deprecated maybe considering use an alternative https://upmostly.com/angular/the-dangers-of-ng-deep-bleeding ?

Comment: yeah I know that, I test with :host also. But the problem is that none of there are working. If I want my SCSS to works, I had to add it in my style.scss and not in my component